# How can the primary key be specified when creating a new model instance in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm using [Django Simple History](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html) to store information about who edited what.  In order to conform to the adage, ["Never Use a Warning When You Mean Undo"](http://alistapart.com/article/neveruseawarning), I am providing users an un-delete option after they do a delete action.  When they do the delete, I do the actual HTTP `DELETE` request to DRF.  When the user clicks un-delete, I need to recreate the object. In order to ease the maintenance of the history of the object, I want to restore the object with the exact same primary key.

Right now, my `HyperLinkedModelSerializer` has both the `id` and `url` fields of the object, but specifying the `id` when posting does not create the object with that `id`, despite the fact that the `id` is available.

How can I specify the `id`/primary key when creating an object in DRF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because [`HyperlinkedModelSerializer`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#hyperlinkedmodelserializer) does not include the `id` field by default.

From the DRF docs:

> By default the serializer will include a `url` field instead of a
>   primary key field.

You will have to **explicitly define the `id` field in the serializer**.

```
class MySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    id = serializers.IntegerField() # explicitly define the 'id' field    
    ...
```

Comment: I swear I tried something like that.  But I did not.  This works.  Thanks Rahul!

Comment: Thanks mate! Worked. This should be more explicit in docs